# UITableView change color of multiple selection checkmarks

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios8

how can I change the tint color of the multiple selection checkmark?

I tried `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];` in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

But it had no effect.

Am I restricted to the colors defined in the documentation of `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` so blue and gray?

Thanks

Comment: what you actually want please elaborate this

Comment: Is it the checkmark (`UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`) whose color you want to change? or the cell selection color? In the first case, simply set the `tintColor` of your cell. For the latter case, @BHASKAR has posted the correct solution.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer changing the `tintColor` of the cell was exactly what I needed. However how do I change the light blue shading of checked rows?

Comment: iOS7 onwards, you will need to set a `selectedBackgroundView` to change the cell selection color, as @BHASKAR has pointed out.

Comment: this changes the color when the row is selected (as in move down the navigation stack) but when you check off a row while editing there is a different lighter blue tone, that is what I would like to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in iOS 7, using

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

will not work as expected, because in iOS 7 this is now gray, even if you pass the constant above. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle

So use this to change color in the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method.

```
UIView *cellBg = [[UIView alloc] init];
cellBg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0)     alpha:1.0]; // this RGB value for blue color
cellBg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
Cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBg;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

Just set the cell tint color in cellForRowAtindexPath for checkmark

```
cell.tintColor = UIColor.yourColor
```

and to change selection color set

```
let cellBackgroundColorView = uiview()

cellBackgroundColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor

cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBackgroundColorView
```